# Symfony monolog doesn't log in prod mode

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

My current problem is that when I activate production mode, no emails are sent with e.g. undefined variables.

When I switch Symfony to dev mode, emails are sent. Only not in Prod mode.

My monolog.yaml:

```
when@prod:
  monolog:
    handlers:
      main:
        type: fingers_crossed
        action_level: error
        handler: deduplicated
        excluded_http_codes: [ 404, 405 ]
      deduplicated:
        type: deduplication
        handler: symfony_mailer
      symfony_mailer:
        type: symfony_mailer
        from_email: '%env(APP_MAIL_SENDER)%'
        to_email: '%env(DEV_EMAIL)%'
        subject: 'An Error Occurred! %%message%%'
        level: debug
        formatter: monolog.formatter.html
        content_type: text/html
```

Comment: Have you tried if emails work at all with production mode? I mean emails other than the monolog's logs.

Comment: This may be off topic but I think you should use Sentry to collect errors instead of receiving emails for errors, you may receive too much emails.

Comment: In production, is your .env.(local) `APP_ENV` set to `prod`?

Comment: Yes, my env is set to prod

Comment: @A.L Do you know about Sentry and how to integrate Sentry into the entire project?

Comment: @Luu see the official documentation: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/guides/symfony/